# Finding an orthogonal matrix with given absolute value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Abs}{Abs}$Define the absolute value of a matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ by
$$
\Abs(A) = 
\pmatrix{|a_{11}| & \cdots & |a_{1n}|\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
|a_{n1}| & \cdots & |a_{nn}|}
$$
Suppose that you are given the absolute value of some unknown orthogonal matrix and you are supposed to find and orthogonal matrix with this absolute value, in other words:

> Find an orthogonal matrix $A$ s.t. $\Abs(A) = B$, where $B = \Abs(C)$ and $C$ is orthogonal.

Matrix $B$ is given, $C$ is unknown. $A$ need not be equal to $C$. I realize this is probably a very tough problem but would there be some smart way to search for $A$?

Comment: In fact you are given $B$, which is $Abs(A)$, $A$ being orthogonal and you are trying to find a $A$ fitting?

Comment: I am trying to find any orthogonal matrix $A$ satisfying the constraint $Abs(A)=B$, and I basically know that at least one solution exists.

Comment: I answered a question like this [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9risimxvbhmd9us/Bhatia%20HW%202.pdf?dl=0) (see "Question II.1.11").  In this context, we're given a matrix whose entries are the squares of the entries of $B$.  These matrices are called "orthostochastic matrices".

Comment: If I have time later, perhaps I'll adapt the proof to the context of your question.

Comment: I'm very interested to know the answer, any news? Specifically, are there situations where several solutions exist?

Comment: roger, I know that in general several solutions do exist. For instance, starting from some 5-by-5 orthogonal matrix, one can get rid of the signs and do an exhaustive search over all possible designations of signs for orthogonal matrices. I just did this and found 512 orthogonal matrices this way, one of them being the original one of course. I no longer work on this particular problem since I found a workaround which gives me sufficient information about the signs for my purposes.

Comment: @roger, see the linked question for a simple proof that shows that there are always several solutions unless we are working with empty matrices (in which case I suppose orthogonal matrices do not exist).

Comment: ok thanks kiro.

Comment: I don't think there is any known smart way. Had an efficient algorithm existed, we would have numerically solved the [Hadamard conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) for all moderate matrix sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly efficient MATLAB solution to the problem. Assume $B$ is a $N$ by $N$ matrix. Execution time is proportional to $(N-1)*2^{N-2}$. For an orthogonal matrix, the dot product of any pair of column vectors must be zero. The algorithm finds the signs of elements of columns $j=2\ldots N$, each column in turn, such that the dot product of the column pair 1 and j is zero.

```
N = 10;
[C,~] = qr(randn(N));       % generate a random orthonormal matrix

B = abs(C);
A = B; 

p2 = pow2(1-N:0)';
for j = 2:N
    for k = 0:2^N/2-1
        w = 1 - 2 * rem(floor( k*p2 ),2);   % convert k to an array of +/-1's
        dot_prod = A(:,1)' * (A(:,j) .* w); % dot prod of columns 1 and j
        if abs(dot_prod) < 10*eps           % done if dot_prod=0
            A(:,j) = A(:,j) .* w;           % update column j with good w
        break
    end
end
```

The elements of the first column and first row of $A$ are positive. The determinant of $A$ will be equal to $\pm1$.